# Creating objects from constructors

Tags: java

I am a newbie to Java, just been fiddling with the code for a while.

```
public class ThreeVector {
private double x,y,z;   // definign local variables 

public ThreeVector(){} // a constructor that has no input

public ThreeVector (double va1,double va2, double va3){va1=x;va2=y;va3=z;};// creatign a constructor , so can be used for calling by a method later
// Takes 3 values 

public double magnitude (){
    double y1= Math.sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z);
    return y1 ; // finds the magnitude of a vector
}

public ThreeVector unitv(){

    ThreeVector unitv= new ThreeVector ();
unitv.ThreeVector(x/magnitude(),y/magnitude(),z/magnitude());
}
```

Now here is where I get stuck. I created an object `unitV` so I could call the `ThreeVector` constructor, but the compiler keeps saying to create a new method for `ThreeVector`.
Not sure whats going on...

Comment: How did you create the object? Can you add the code that is trying to use `ThreeVector`?

Comment: Read http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-constructors

Comment: You have a method defined as `public ThreeVector unitv()...` but does not return an instance of a ThreeVector. I think you want to remove the unitv method and do something like Luiggi suggests.

Comment: As a matter to style, you should consider making the class final (so it can't be subclassed) and probably the doubles in it too.  Code using your ThreeVector class will be much easier to understand and debug if ThreeVector is immutable.  You will have to make the no-arg constructor explicitly set 'x = 0.0; y = 0.0; z = 0.0' (assuming that is the intent of the no-arg version).

Comment: If you do decide that ThreeVector should be immutable there is probably no point having the no-arg constructor BTW.  Define a 'public static final ThreeVector ZERO = new ThreeVector(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);'.  Now you have a constant which represents the 'zero' vector.

Comment: `ThreeVector unitv = new ThreeVector ` , thats how I created the object unit v

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A constructor can be called **only** using the `new` keyword. What you're doing here:

```
unitv.ThreeVector(x/magnitude(),y/magnitude(),z/magnitude());
```

is calling a method called `ThreeVector`, so the compiler complains that there's no such method in your `ThreeVector` class.

To fix this, you must use the `ThreeVector` constructor with the arguments to create your `unitv` instance instead:

```
public ThreeVector unitv(){
    ThreeVector unitv = new ThreeVector(x/magnitude(),y/magnitude(),z/magnitude());
    //and, of course, return this ThreeVector instance
    return unitv;
}
```

And this code can be shorten to

```
public ThreeVector unitv() {
    return new ThreeVector(x/magnitude(),y/magnitude(),z/magnitude());
}
```

But since you can have your `x`, `y` and `z` with `0` value at the same time, it would be better to change the logic in your `unitv` method to first get the `magnitude` value and doing an evaluation, this in order to avoid a division by 0:

```
public ThreeVector unitv() {
    double magnitude = magnitude();
    if (magnitude != 0) {
        return new ThreeVector(x/magnitude, y/magnitude, z/magnitude);
    }
    return new ThreeVector(0, 0, 0);
}
```

---

By the way, your constructor logic is wrong, you're assigning the fields values to the arguments, it should be the other way around:

```
public ThreeVector (double va1,double va2, double va3) {
    x = va1;
    y = va2;
    z = va3
}
```

Comment: ThreeVector unitv= new ThreeVector (); I mean isnt that what the above line is doing ? Sorry for my ignorance just completely new to this

Comment: @RobinPhilip in the first sentence of my answer, I'm explaining that you can call a constructor using the `new` keyword. When you do `unitv.ThreeVector(...)` you're not calling the constructor with three parameters, instead calling a method called `ThreeVector` that doesn't exists, thus the compiler is giving you problems.

Comment: Thanks LUiggi got it , and all the others :)

Answer (score 0):

No you need to directly call the constructor:

```
ThreeVector unitv= new ThreeVector(x,y,z);
```

Only after this you can call the magnitude method

Also your constructor does the assignments the wrong way:

Should be:
    public ThreeVector (double va1,double va2, double va3){x = va1;y = va2;z=va3;}

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize a `new ThreeVector(va1, va2, va3)`.

**Attention**

Your code in the constructor is wrong.

```
{
    // instance field assigned to argument        
    va1=x;va2=y;va3=z;
}
```

... should be:

```
{
    // argument assigned to instance field
    x = va1;
    y = va2;
    z = va3;
}
```